# Control volume of mpg123

Tags: python, audio

Good time of day! Currently developing something like "smart home" and I need to start different audio streams with different volume level. For example, I want to hear background music with 20% of original volume but in case if someone press door bell then I want to hear that bell ring with 100% volume. For my purposes currently, I'm using `mpg123` with Python scripts. Python script with `pexpect` runs mpg123 with needed settings like

```
mpg123 -vC <filename>
```

Current approach sends `'s'` like pause immediately after the player starts. Then I'm sending needed count of `'-'` like decrease volume by 2 to the player and resume it. Huh... it works but an implementation is ugly, and there is some gap between the player start and volume decreasing. At least I hear few first "packets" before python script actually pauses player and decrease volume.

Is there any way to reduce the volume by some command? 
Is there any way to start mpg123 paused? At least to eliminate that gap

Thanks!

Comment: Pulseaudio or ALSA? Under Pulseaudio, you can control the volume per application, and it remembers the last volume by name of application. Some tools like `paplay` have options to set application or stream name. With `pacmd`, and you can script volume changes etc. Under ALSA< it's going to be a lot more difficult.

Comment: I can use pulse or ALSA but I will be glad to use some higher level tool like player and control volume in it, not in system mixer

Answer (score 5):

i do the same for bluetooth audio management in smart home and use the following

```
mpg123 -f -2000 test.mp3
```

the maximum value of the amplitude is 100% which coressponds to 32768, i use a value of 2000 which is about 6.1 %, for more details see the manual `man mpg123`

I dont suggest to use pulse, just use alsa internally with mpg123

have fun

Answer (score 0):

Options for Pulseaudio:

1) Stream the output of `mpg123` into `paplay`, for example with something like

```
mpg123 --stdout ... | paplay --rate=44100 --format=s16le --channels=2 --stream-name=Music --client-name=Musicplayer --volume=65536
```

You can either set the volume on the commandline as above, or set the volume once in `pavucontrol` by client-name, and the next time the same application starts it will remember the volume. So if you use different client names, say `Musicplayer` and `Bellringer`, you can pre-set the volume once and for all, without having it to change from Python.

2) Use some other program to play MP3 files that uses Pulseaudio and either can set the client name, or has a recognizable client name, or has a option to set the volume. E.g.

```
mplayer -volume=... ...
```

Then you have the same options as above.

3) Use `pamcd` or `pactl` to set the volume of the stream that's playing, e.g.

```
pacmd set-sink-input-volume 42 50%
```

You can use something similar to

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs | egrep '(index)|(name)'
```

to find the index numer for a given stream or client name. Or parse the complete output in Python.

4) Use the DBUS interface of Pulseaudio from Python. This will require some programming.

I wouldn't advise to use Python with `pexpect` to somehow change the volume through the UI, that looks like a horrible kludge, and isn't really "higher level".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is really helpful! Do you know any other ways to interact with the player? It will be good for me to softly increase/decrease volume value. Thanks!

Comment: With `mpg123`? No, I don't know ways to interact with it, and I wouldn't try. You can change the volume smoothly via `pacmd` or DBus.